# How to convert a set of features to a count matrix in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, gensim

Given a matrix

----`d1 d2 d3
 a: v1  0  v2
 b: v1  v3  0`

I want

----`v1 v2 v3
 a: 1  1   0
 b: 1  0   1`

I remember vaguely that this can be done with `Gensim`...but there must also be some module in pandas? I have tried to do `for v in v: for el in [a,b]`(happy to post the code, but I think that the example is clear enough) but it is very slow, and I imagine this must have been solved before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`pandas.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html), e.g.

```
import pandas as pd

# create your dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(index=['a', 'b'],
                  data={'d1': ['v1', 'v1'],
                        'd2': [None, 'v3'],
                        'd3': ['v2', None]})

# perform one-hot encoding
df = pd.get_dummies(df, prefix_sep='=')

# rename if you so wish
df.rename(columns={c: c.split('=')[1] for c in df.columns}, inplace=True)

# sort columns by name (not really necessary)
df.sort_index(axis=1, inplace=True)

# have a look
print df
```

which yields

```
   v1  v2  v3
a   1   1   0
b   1   0   1
```

Answer (score 1):

Start with your DataFrame `DF`, with `0` replaced with `NaN`

```
DF=ps.DataFrame({'d1':['v1','v1'],'d2':[NaN,'v3'],'d3':['v2',NaN]},index=['a','b'])
```

Get the unique values you want to count:

```
Vals=DF.stack().unique()
```

use some list comprehension for counts:

```
ps.DataFrame([[(DF.ix[ind,:]==Vi).sum() for Vi in Vals] for ind in DF.index] , columns=Vals, index=DF.index)
```